# Is there a better than $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm for the following question: $A,B$ sets, $|A|=n,|B|=n-1,B\subset A$, calculate $A\setminus B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

### The Problem:

I am looking for a fast algorithm for the following trivial-looking question:

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $A,B$ be sets of integers such that
>
> - $|A|=n$
> - $|B|=n-1$
> - $B\subset A$
>
> Calculate the single element of $A \setminus B$.

**Note:** Even though mathematically I am denoting $A$ and $B$ as sets, computationally they are handled as **lists**. So I will denote the $i$'th element of $A$ as $A[i]$ and the $j$'th element of $B$ as $B[j]$. It is important to mention that $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily ordered the same way.

### Example:

$A := \{6,5,1,7,9\}$, $B := \{9,1,5,6\}$, then $A \setminus B = \{7\}$.

**Note:** Computationally the numbers inside $A$ and $B$ appear one after the other, so what the computer sees is

$$A[1] = 6, A[2] = 5, \dots, B[1] = 9, \dots,B[4] = 6$$

### $O(n^2)$ algorithm:

There is a trivial $O(n^2)$ algorithm that can calculate $A \setminus B$. This is its code in Python:

```
def A_minus_B(A,B):
    for a in A:
        is_a_in_B = False
        for b in B:
            if a == b:
                is_a_in_B = True
        if not is_a_in_B:
            return a
```

It checks all pairs of numbers in $A$ and $B$, and if it doesn't find a pair for an $a \in A$, it returns that as its output.

However it never considers the fact that $B \subset A$.

Obviously this is an $O(n^2)$ algorithm. It makes $n(n-1)$ steps in the worst case, if the single $A \setminus B$ element appears at the last position of the input list $A$.

### $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm:

This is a faster algorithm. This time, instead of giving a Python code, I will simply outline the algorithm:

$1$. Sort $A$ in increasing order in $O(n\log(n))$ steps.
$2$. Sort $B$ in increasing order in $O((n-1)\log(n-1))$ steps.
$3$. Go through both $A$ and $B$ in at most $n-1$ steps with $i=1$ to $i=n-1$. If $A[i] \ne B[i]$, then $A[i]$ has to be the single element of $A \setminus B$. If all elements are equal from $i=1$ to $i=n-1$, then return $A[n]$.

Steps $1$ and $2$ can be done in $O(n\log(n))$ steps, and Step $3$ can be done in $O(n)$ steps, so this algorithm is $O(n\log(n))$.

### Question:

Is there a better algorithm? I refuse to believe that such a simple problem cannot be solved in linear time. Somehow we need to use that $A$ is almost the same set as $B$. What makes this difficult is that the elements of $A$ and $B$ can appear in any order.

### Context:

I am constructing an algorithm that works with [Vines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vine_copula). Here, any cluster can be thought of as set $A$ in the above problem, and any connecting separator can be thought of as set $B$. Calculating $A \setminus B$ gives us the element which has the lowest mutual information with the rest of $A$, which, among other things, is useful to give an ordering for the entire Vine structure.

Comment: Without sorting: compute $a=\sum_{x\in A}x$ and $b=\sum_{x\in B}x$ in $O(n)$ steps, then return $\{a-b\}$.

Comment: Wow! How did I not think about that.

Comment: Of course this is not be the best solution in practice and there is the possibility of integer overflows if $n$ or the integers are “large”…

Comment: Depending on your model of computation, @nejmban's algorithm may really be $O(n \log n)$, as you need to deal with numbers having on the order of $\log(n)$ bits.

Comment: I think fundamentally the issue is that once you start counting the bits of the numbers, the size of the input for the problem as specified ($|A|=n$) is no longer just $O(n)$ but is $O(n\log n).$ You're not going to find an algorithm that runs without examining all of the input, so $O(n\log n)$ is the best you can do. But that leaves open the possibility of an algorithm that is $O(N)$ where $N$ is the size of the input.

Answer (score 2):

There are two plausible algorithms.  One is to compute $\sum_{x \in A} x$ and $\sum_{x \in B} x$ and compute their difference; then $\sum_{x \in A} x - \sum_{x \in B} x$ is the missing value.  This runs in $O(n)$ time if all of the numbers are small, or if you are working in the RAM model / transdichotomous model.

Another is to store $B$ in a hash table, then for each element of $A$, check whether it is present in the hash table.  In the worst case the running time could be $O(n^2)$.  However if you use an appropriate hash function (e.g., a 2-universal hash chosen randomly), you can show that the average running time is $O(n)$, and moreover one can show that the probability the running time takes more than $cn + o(n)$ time drops exponentially rapidly in $c$.  Again, this assume you are working in the RAM model / transdichotomous model.

Comment: Computing $\sum_{x\in A}x - \sum_{x\in B}x$ for $|A|=n$ and $|B|=n-1$ is always at least $O(n\log(n))$. That's because of the following: All elements of $A$ are different (as it's a set), so at best its elements are the numbers $\{1,\dots,n\}$. So at best the average size of a number in $A$ is $O(\log(n))$. Now adding $n$ numbers of size $O(\log(n))$ takes $O(n\log(n))$ binary operations.

Comment: @DanielP, not in the RAM model / transdichotomous model, as assumed in my answer.  In those models, you can add two numbers of that size in $O(1)$ time.